# Dynamics CRM - Have to uninstall and install Profiler many times to debug in Plugin Registration Tool

Tags: debugging, profiler, dynamics-crm-online

I got into a trouble that my Replay Plug-in Execution never retrieved new log after the first time.

Here are my current step to debug my plugin:

1. Install Profiler
2. Open Step to Start Profiling
   [image]
3. Open CRM and update field
4. Back to Plugin Registration Tool --> Debug
   [image]
5. Select Profile from CRM
   [image]
6. Back CRM again and update field
7. Back to Plugin Registration Tool --> Debug
8. Nothing update from the log

I then tried to reinstall Profiler and I can only debug with the first update in CRM.

It takes me a lot of time for that and I don't have any clue to fix it.

Thus, it would be great if you could help me address the problem :-)

Answer (score 2):

This happens because entity plugin profile can hold only 100 records.
Now go to crm advanced find and search for entity plugin profile, delete old record and may be keep just 10-20 reocrds.
Now log into plugin registration tool agin refresh your environment and you will see the latest profiled log to select.